# An error in setup documentation of the Firebase SDK for android

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle

It seems to be an error in the Firebase setup documentation for android...
[Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

The documentation says to add this to build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        } 
    }
}
```

This didn't work for me and i found this solution here on Stackoverflow (add maven{...} in repositories and not in dependencies):

```
allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        } 
    }
}
```

The question is: why this works and how Firebase official documentation can be wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you add some links to the official documentation?

Comment: @Pelocho this is the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: Sorry for forgetting the link XD edited...

Answer (score 0):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

write this code in project level build.gradle.

Comment: Sorry but i already found the solution (as written above), the problem is that the official documentation seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommended you to take this following approach

**Step 1**:- Login to google account from android studio you can find this option on top right corner

**Step 2**:- Go to Tools>Firebase

It will bring Firebase Assistance panel to right hand side

**Step 3**:- Click on service you want to use and it will set the project for you

Refer this screenshot On right you can see Firebase Assistance page
[image]

Comment: Hi @Akshay , I already found the solution (as written above), the problem is that the official documentation seems to be wrong and i'm trying to understand why...